# Custom font being cut off on webpage

Tags: css, fonts

Here's a page showing my problem:

http://coreyyoungcorp.com/font-issue/
[image]

I have no idea why it's being cut off. It's not a `line-height` issue nor a font size issue, but I can't for the life of me figure out why on earth it's happening, and only with this font "Oswald".

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Your link wants to store data on my computer for offline use.

Comment: i have no idea why that is. there's nothing in that directory at all except php/css/js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"Light"` and `"Bold"` fonts are the problem. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/FHCXf/1/

Comment: perfect! i structured the fonts like that because i read on here that it's the best way to include different styles for a font. i usually structure it the way you did in the jsfiddle. didn't know it would mess with how it appears.

Comment: @CoreyRS They may have been right or wrong; I set it up like that to find if there was any real differences happening between them. Definitely doesn't matter what order its in, in HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=152) with Chrome on Windows for Oswald fonts and similar font families.

Changing the `font-weight` property to `normal` works sometimes, but it defeats the purpose if you have a bold or light font style.

Comment: `font-weight: normal;` just fixed my issue in Chrome.